# Why Aspx page get reloaded after javascript call

Tags: asp.net, .net

Below is the code of a simple page with a button.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="AdminPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="School.AdminPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calling() {
        var user = "all";
        alert(user)
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<button runat="server" onclick="calling()">
    Mybutton</button>
</asp:Content>
```

On click of button, alert appear and when i click ok on that alert dialog box...page gets reloaded....why it get reloaded and how to stop this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "default event" is occurring.

To disable it, use return before you function call as follows:

```
<button runat="server" onclick="return calling()">
```

And in the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function calling() {
       var user = "all";
       alert(user);
       return false;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to close alert without refreshing page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return ;
    }
</script>
```